# Is it possible to use NCover plug-in in Jenkins to get code coverage on c# code with VSTest?

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to use `NCover` plug-in in Jenkins to get code coverage on c# code with `VSTest`? I found help on how to user `NCover` with `MSTests` but not `VSTests`. Is there any other Jenkins tool to get code coverage using `VSTests`?

Answer (score 0):

I take it by your reference to the NCover plug-in that you're using NCover 3?
In any case, NCover 5 can cover any .NET test runner from a Jenkins build script.
In the case of VSTest, it's usually a matter of profiling vstest.executionengine.